# Is $\{(x,\sin(1/x)) :x\in (0,1]\}$ locally connected?

Tags: general-topology

> Is $\{(x,\sin(1/x)) :x\in (0,1]\}$ locally connected?

I have read the answer from my textbook and found the answer is no. But there isn't an explanation. I'm stuck on this problem.
Anyone could tell me how to make clear the open subsets in this topology? Or other ways to get the conclusion?

Comment: That set, as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is locally connected. You probably saw the claim about its closure $\{(x,\sin(1/x)):x\in(0,1]\}\cup\{(0,x):x\in[-1,1]\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In the latter, the points in $\{(0,x):x\in[-1,1]\}$ are the ones that all their small enough neighborhoods are disconnected.

Comment: The set in the question is locally connected and, in fact, it is homeomorphic to $(0,1]$ via the map $(x,y)\mapsto x$.

Comment: Sorry, But why aren't those points' small neighbourhoods are disconnected?

Comment: You'd better check the definition of *locally connected* carefully. It does not require that every neighborhood of $p$ in the set be itself connected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That set is homeomorphic to $(0,1]$ via the map $x \to (x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}))$ which has the first projection as its inverse. So connected and locally connected.

It's the union with $\{(0,0)\}$ or $\{0\} \times [-1,1]$ (the topologist's sine curve) that is not locally connected (but still connected).